# creating database via bash with dash in database-name

Tags: mysql, bash

I try to create a new Database via bash which has a dash in the name.

Thats what I tried:

```
echo "CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS db-name CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci" | mysql -uuser -ppw
```

That fails with the following error:

```
ERROR 1064 (42000) at line 1: You have an error in your SQL syntax;
check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the 
right syntax to use near
'-name CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci' at line 1
```

I added backticks then:

```
echo "CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS `db-name` CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci" | mysql -uuser -ppw

ERROR 1064 (42000) at line 1: You have an error in your SQL syntax;
check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the 
right syntax to use near
'CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci' at line 1
```

I played around a bit and found out that mysql doesnt like backticks even without a dash in the name:

```
echo "CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS `dbname` CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci" | mysql -uuser -ppw

ERROR 1064 (42000) at line 1: You have an error in your SQL syntax;
check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the 
right syntax to use near
'CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci' at line 1
```

I am kinda confused. Whats wrong here?

PS: In phpmyadmin it works as expected when adding backticks

Answer (score 54, accepted):

Either you quote the backticks or simply use single quotes instead double quotes around the command:

```
mysql -uuser -ppw -e 'CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS `db-name` CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci'
```

Otherwise the shell would expand the backticks to a command substitution. Check this: http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/commandsub.html

Further note that you don't need the echo command. You can use the `-e` commandline option of mysql

Comment: I didnt know that backticks have to be escaped. Thank you!

Comment: any things wrong it did not work for me ? Command --->

mysql -uroot -pmysql -e 'CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS `mifosplatform-tenants`';

Comment: Hard to say. I recommend opening a question if it still doesn't work for you

Answer (score 4):

Use with backslahes before backticks:

```
mysql -uuser -ppw -e 'CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS \`db-name\` CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci'
```

Answer (score 0):

The correct way is to add back-ticks around the database name, like you do it with field names for example. Single quotes will not work usually.

```
CREATE DATABASE `db-name`;
```